# Azure Resource Graph query | get VM license benefit type

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I can get a no of things about VMs from "resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'" and then expanding the properties. What I am looking for is the Windows license type. The same information is available on the portal under "Virtual Machines" - add Columns - "OS licensing benefit". The values are of type "Azure hybrid benefit", "Not enabled" etc.

I can get the same information for SQL Server on IaaS via properties.sqlServerLicenseType in microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines, so guessing there is a way to get it for VMs? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of how the Portal is checking for that property and generating the column values (portal also displays "Not supported" for Linux, which you can add logic for if required):

```
resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| extend HybridBenefit = iif(properties.licenseType == "Windows_Server", "Azure Hybrid Benefit", "Not Enabled")
```

Comment: Perfect - also answered by @MSFTdocs on github / product docs page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53811) is duplicate of your ask in GitHub. Sharing for the benefit of broader audience.